# Saltstack rpm package install fails

Tags: centos, centos6, rpm, saltstack

So i got these errors while run salt -G 'os:centos' state.apply

```
----------
      ID: filebeat
Function: pkg.installed
  Result: False
 Comment: An exception occurred in this state: Traceback (most recent call la   st):
            File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/salt/state.py", line 1744,    in call
              **cdata['kwargs'])
            File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/salt/loader.py", line 1702   , in wrapper
              return f(*args, **kwargs)
            File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/salt/states/pkg.py", line    1442, in installed
              **kwargs)
            File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/salt/modules/yumpkg.py", l   ine 1111, in install
              rpm_info = __salt__['lowpkg.bin_pkg_info'](pkg_source)
            File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/salt/modules/rpm.py", line    120, in bin_pkg_info
              for field in pkginfo._fields:
          AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_fields'
 Started: 07:57:34.542126
Duration: 10800.412 ms
```

### Changes:

This is part of my .yml file.

```
    filebeat:
   pkg.installed:
      {% if grains['os'] == 'Debian' or 'Ubuntu' %}
      - sources:
         - filebeat: https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/beats/filebeat/filebeat-
5.1.2-amd64.deb
      {% elif grains['os'] == 'Centos' %}
      - sources:
         - filebeat : https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/beats/filebeat/filebeat
-5.1.2-x86_64.rpm
      {% endif %}
```

Comment: Is it bug or i'm missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay i made this working in retarded way, maybe someone will tell me the better way sometimes here.

```
    filebeat:
   pkg.installed:
      {% if grains['os'] == 'Debian' or 'Ubuntu' %}
      - sources:
         - filebeat: https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/beats/filebeat/filebeat-5.1.2-amd64.deb
      {% endif %}
      {% if grains['os'] == 'CentOS' %}
      - sources:
         - filebeat: https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/beats/filebeat/filebeat-5.1.2-x86_64.rpm
      {% endif %}
```

Comment: You changed several things - the match on `grains['os']` (`Centos` vs. `CentOS`), an extra space after the second `filebeat`, and the if/then/else syntax. Which one of these had caused the ugly traceback? That one should be reported as a bug.

Comment: @JosipRodin after if/then/else statement change it started working.